# Fashion MNIST using CNN , Overfitting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
cnn_model = Sequential()

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(64,3, 3, input_shape = (28,28,1), activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

cnn_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

cnn_model.add(Flatten())
cnn_model.add(Dense(output_dim = 32, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_model.add(Dense(output_dim = 10, activation = 'sigmoid'))

cnn_model.compile(loss ='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),metrics =['accuracy'])

epochs = 50

history = cnn_model.fit(X_train,
                        y_train,
                        batch_size = 512,
                        nb_epoch = epochs,
                        verbose = 1,
                        validation_data = (X_validate, y_validate))
```

I get this result at the end:

```
Epoch 50/50
48000/48000 [==============================] - 35s 728us/step - loss: 0.1265 - accuracy: 0.9537 - val_loss: 0.2425 - val_accuracy: 0.9167
training loss=0.125 ,validation loss=0.2425
training accuracy=95.3% ,validation accuracy=91.67
```

My question is as follows:

1. Is the model over-fitting or under-fitting?
2. Should I increase no. of epoch?

[Graph of Losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTBEW.png)

Comment: I think the plot speaks for itself. It's overfitting, and no, more epochs won't help.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Model is Over fitting, you can

1. `Shuffle` the Data, by using `shuffle=True` in `cnn_model.fit`.
2. Use `Early Stopping`
3. Use `Regularization`

Complete code, using same architecture as yours, with reduced Over fitting, is shown below. There has been increase in Loss but we can improve it by adding more Convolutional and Pooling Layers.

```
# To support both python 2 and python 3
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals
from io import open

# Common imports
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from matplotlib.pyplot import axis as ax

tf.__version__

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="X")
X_reshaped = tf.reshape(X, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="y")

# instantiate regularizer
Regularizer = l2(0.001)

cnn_model = Sequential()

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(64,3, 3, input_shape = (28,28,1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))

cnn_model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

cnn_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

cnn_model.add(Flatten())

cnn_model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))

cnn_model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = 'sigmoid', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))

cnn_model.compile(loss ='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),metrics =['accuracy'])

epochs = 50

cnn_model.summary()

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
X_train_reshaped = tf.reshape(X_train, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
X_test_reshaped = tf.reshape(X_test, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

y_train = tf.cast(y_train, dtype = tf.int32)

y_test = tf.cast(y_test, dtype = tf.int32)

def shuffle_batch(X, y, batch_size):
    rnd_idx = np.random.permutation(len(X))
    n_batches = len(X) // batch_size
    for batch_idx in np.array_split(rnd_idx, n_batches):
        X_batch, y_batch = X[batch_idx], y[batch_idx]
        yield X_batch, y_batch

#steps_per_epoch = X_train_reshaped.shape[0]//512
steps_per_epoch = X_train_reshaped.shape[0].value//512

epochs = 50

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)

history = cnn_model.fit(x = X_train_reshaped,
                        y = y_train,
                        batch_size = 512,
                        epochs = epochs, callbacks=[callback],
                        verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test_reshaped, y_test),
                        validation_steps = 10, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, shuffle = True)

print(history.history.keys())

#  "Accuracy"
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# "Loss"
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
axes = plt.axes()
axes.set_ylim([0.2, 1.5])
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```